# How to define the Cache-Control header on an S3 object via a signed URL?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Following the instructions in [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node), I've managed to get uploads working via signed URLs. It looks something like this:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3();

const s3Params = {
  Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
  Key: fileName,
  Expires: 60,
  ContentType: fileType,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  CacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
  // ...
});
```

...except my `CacheControl` param (which I added myself; it isn't in the guide) does not seem to take effect. When I use the above code to generate a signed URL and upload something to it, the resulting object in S3 is served with no `Cache-Control` header.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You must send the `Cache-Control` header in the upload request, regardless of what you set during the signed URL generation.**

Whether this is a bug or an intentional behaviour is questionable and beyond my ability to answer. The `Cache-Control` header, as you noticed, is part of the signed URL, but for whatever reason the information is completely ignored during the file upload, ie. not specifying a `CacheControl` property in the `getSignedUrl()` function still allows the client to set `Cache-Control` header to whatever value they choose.

If you need to have control over the `Cache-Control` header, then using the `getSignedUrl()` is most likely not appropriate for your use case.

### Solution

AWS now supports a new signature scheme, called [AWS Signature version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html) which allows full control over what the upload request may or may not contain, including **which headers** are sent and with what values.

The JavaScript SDK supports this new signature version: [`createPresignedPost()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property).

A detailed example of how to generate this pre-signed `POST` policy and how the upload form should look like can be found directly on [AWS's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

Even though the example demonstrates the file upload via standard http upload `<form>` element, the principles can be applied to any client/consumer capable of performing HTTP communication.

#### Example

For completeness, here is the example (taken from AWS documentation page linked above) of how a pre-signed `POST` policy looks like:

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

This POST policy sets the following conditions on the request:

- The upload must occur before midnight UTC on December 30, 2015.
- The content can be uploaded only to the `sigv4examplebucket`. The bucket must be in the region that you specified in the credential scope (`x-amz-credential` form parameter), because the signature you provided is valid only within this scope.
- You can provide any key name that starts with `user/user1`. For example, `user/user1/MyPhoto.jpg`.
- The ACL must be set to `public-read`.
- If the upload succeeds, the user's browser is redirected to `http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html`.
- The object must be an image file.
- The `x-amz-meta-uuid` tag must be set to `14365123651274`.
- The `x-amz-meta-tag` can contain any value.

Note that the list of conditions in this example is not exhaustive and `CacheControl` **is** supported. See the [creating a POST policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) document for what you can do with this.

Comment: This is totally not correct, you can set `ResponseCacheControl` in the `s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', options)` options

Comment: This question and answer is related to controlling `Cache-Control` restrictions during file uploads (`putObject`), not file downloads. ⚠️

Comment: This root of the issue is though `resulting object in S3 is served with no Cache-Control header`. By using a signed `getObject` with `ResponseCacheControl` you can work around it.

Comment: I tried and got `Unexpected key 'ResponseCacheControl' found in params`.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what the accepted answer says, you can add `Cache-Control` to the URL obtained from the getSignedURL, **but only for the getObject operation**. I hope this helps people who came here for `getObject`.

This is what I have done

```
    const params = {
      Bucket: <YOUR_S3_BUCKET>,
      Key: <YOUR_KEY>,
      ResponseCacheControl: `public, max-age=900, immutable`,
      Expires: 900 // default value
    }

    return this.S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)
```

The resulting URL looks like this

```
https://<YOUR_S3_BUCKET>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_KEY>?...&response-cache-control=public%2C%20max-age%3D900%2C%20immutable
```

and the response header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=900, immutable`

Check out the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) and notice the params in the last example. You can find the `ResponseCacheControl` and `Expires` params there.

If you look at the docs, you can see that `putObject` contains the `CacheControl` param but adding that to params does not do anything.